# Is there a knapsack algorithm for packing boxes by item dimension?

Tags: python, knapsack-problem, bin-packing

Trying to self teach myself python and running into an issue. Can someone confirm this would be a knapsack problem?

Example: I have two items, one 3" x 3" x 3", the other 1" x 3" x 9". I have a list of 12 different box sizes, ordered by cost from cheapest to highest.

Can I use knapsack to determine which of the 12 boxes these two items will fit in together and return the cheapest option? Or would something else like a genetic algorithm be better to calculate the minimal 9" x 4" x 3" size and pull back the corresponding box?

Everything I've seen so far is based on a single weight (volume) and in this case item 1 and item 2 cannot be viewed as the same.

Example Box Sizes:

A - 2 x 6 x 6, $.52

B - 12 x 10 x 4, $.54

C - 14 x 12 x 5, $.71

The output would need be box B as the items would fit in both B & C but B is the cheapest.

Any help would be very appreciated.

***Edit for clarification***

I've made a basic excel file to handle this using SORT and COUNTIFS etc. but it can't handle anything complex like eight of a 3 x 3 x 3 item fitting in a 6 x 6 x 6 box.

Comment: You can review a deterministic Java implementation of this problem, which accounts for orthogonal rotation and weight, at https://github.com/mohitesh07/3d-bin-packing/blob/master/BinPacking.java but it minimises the number of boxes, not the sumproduct of box count-price.

Comment: You may want to look on cs.stackexchange too, [here is a related question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1478/algorithms-for-two-and-three-dimensional-knapsack)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can be treated as a multiply-constrained multiple knapsack problem, or more generally as a bin packing problem. The exact approach will be dictated by language and how you want to tradeoff CPU efficiency, development time, versatility, etc. (cheap, fast, good: pick two)

Here's how I would phrase the problem description: **minimise the combined cost of the integer quantity of knapsack(s) required with sufficient X, Y and Z capacity to hold the required items**.
Phrasing this 'mathmatically' would be harder for me than just implementing it, given that it's clearly NP-hard.

The most-optimal algorithm depends on the goals/tradeoffs. I would bash out a working solution and some comprehensive test cases for benchmarking other approaches. Off the top of my head I would think about these approaches:

1. (pre-)sort boxes by cost ascending
2. sort items by volume descending
3. first-fit pack the items into boxes (when any sum of item dimension exceeds box dimension, instantiate the first box which has a sufficiently large length)

Or

1. sort boxes by (cost/volume) increasing
2. sort items by volume decreasing
3. traverse items, first-fit items into free space in currently part-filled boxes, or allocate the first box which is sufficiently large
4. repeat traversal until all items packaged

More thoughts:

- can we shuffle lists or choose boxes randomly?
- how do we know the objective is a minima? Is it local or global minimum?
- how do we know if a part-filled box has enough room for a particular item? <sup>1</sup>
- should we just randomly package until CPUtime or memory is exhausted, then use the cheapest solution?
- can we be smart and use graph theory?
- is this a really a timetabling problem?
- there are a finite combination of boxes which satisfies the problem and only integer quantities of box can be used so maybe generate (all?) possible combinations, then solve with a simplex algorithm?

---

You may also wish to require a certain amount of slack fill. You might want to (later) limit weight per box. There will be edge cases, such as when the cost of the boxes will be greater than a pallet, or ISO container, etc. so perhaps the problem can be bounded.

---

<sup>1</sup> all items and boxes have L, W, D > 0 and L >= W >= D. (X, Y, Z) of occupied space is the convex hull of each item placed next to each other, which depends on orientation (rotation) and location! So do you solve this problem first? Do you ignore rotation? Worst cases with rotation irrelevant, items are cubes of side-length L or spheres of diameter L with the associated packing density 0.64 to 0.74. <sup>2</sup>

<sup>2</sup> you know, the more I think about this, and the longer I spend tapping out this answer on my phone, the more it occurs to me that Jeff Bezos must have spent a fortune on this!

---

**Edit**:

`pip install py3dbp` [provides an implementation of a 3d bin packing algorithm](https://github.com/enzoruiz/3dbinpacking) which may help bootstrap your solution to minimising cost. The paper it references may be useful to you.

Comment: Just realised you specified, but didn't tag [python], so I don't know how to best approach an optimisation problem not in C/Matlab. There's probably a bunch of stuff in `scipy` that's of use.

Comment: Might have been useful for Jeff back in the day... now they are so obsessed with one day shipping they don't bother with this sort of optimization. Thanks for the head start... my weekend is now probably shot working through this.